# XAML: Bind to a single child in a collection

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0

I have a class like this:

```
public class Contest {
    List<ContestTeam> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class ContestTeam {
    int TeamId { get; set; }
    int FinalScore { get; set; }
}
```

And my view model looks like this:

```
public class ScheduleViewModel {
    int CurrentTeamId { get; }
    List<Contest> Schedule { get; }
}
```

My XAML looks something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Schedule}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- TODO: DataContext is currently hard coded to 425 - this needs to be fixed -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            DataContext="{Binding Path=Teams, Converter={StaticResource CurrentTeam}, ConverterParameter=425}">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Button Content="Delete" />
                </StackPanel>

                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
                    <!-- a list of all the teams -->
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Essentially, so I can continue developing I created a value converter (CurrentTeam) and hard-coded the `TeamId` as the `ConverterParameter` so I can continue developing the view. But I'm at a bit of an impasse. Is there a way (using XAML) to bind the `DataContext` of the `StackPane`l to the `ContestTeam` in the `Teams` collection that matches the value of `ScheduleViewModel.TeamId`?

My last recourse will be to just use the `Loaded` event of the `StackPanel` to set it's `DataContext` in the code-behind, but I'd like to avoid that. Are there any XAML Ninjas out there who can help me figure this out?

Comment: You can create a `IValueConverter` which derives from `DependencyObject` and has some `DependencyProperty` which holds the `Id` for `Silverlight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to make queries in XAML bindings. In this case, since you really have two input values (`Teams` and `CurrentTeamId`), just use a `MultiBinding` and a `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class FindContestByIdConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var teams = (IEnumerable<ContestTeam>)values[0];
        var teamId = (int)values[1];
        return teams.Single(t => t.TeamId == teamId);
    }

    // ConvertBack that throws NotSupportedException
    ...
}
```

and then XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.DataContext>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FindContestByIdConverter}">
      <Binding Path="Teams"/>
      <Binding Path="CurrentTeamId" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </StackPanel.DataContext>
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Silverlight doesn't support multibinding yet - but I found this link:http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/06/silverlight-multibindings-how-to-attached-mutiple-bindings-to-a-single-property/

Comment: How to implement `ConvertBack`

Comment: For most multibindings there's really no way to recreate the original two (or more) values out of the final one, so you just throw NotSupportedException, and that's that. If you need a two-way binding, you need to describe exactly how you expect it to work before that question can be answered.